# read and write to a csv file

Tags: python, pandas

While working with the pandas library, I want to read and write data to a csv file.  Everything is going fine using to_csv to write the DataFrame to the csv file.  My problem arises when I try to read the values back to the python interpreter.

The parameter index_col=None doesn't change the output.

```
#Pass some keys and values to a pandas DataFrame held in variable df
df = pd.DataFrame({'Artist':['Sublime','Blink 182','Nirvana'],
'Album':['Sublime','Blink 182','Nevermind'],
'Hit Single':["What I've Got", 'All the Small Things',
'Smells Like Teen Spirit']})

#Print DataFrame
df


#Write the data to a spreadsheet(comma separated value file type)
df.to_csv('filename.csv')

#Read the values back into the df varaible
df =pd.read_csv('filename.csv')

#Print out values in df variable
df
```

After reading the data back using read_csv there is Unnamed: at the top of the second column as well as an extra set of numeric indices counting up from 0 to 2 0 appearing twice.  How can I get rid of this extra unwanted column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need to read the `index` read the file with

`df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv", index_col=0)`

if you don't, save it with

`df.to_csv('filename.csv', index=False)`

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are saving the `index` to the file. You can use:

```
df.to_csv('filename.csv', index=False)

df =pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
df
Out[1]:
    Artist      Album       Hit Single
0   Sublime     Sublime     What I've Got
1   Blink 182   Blink 182   All the Small Things
2   Nirvana     Nevermind   Smells Like Teen Spirit
```

This should prevent the extra column from being created, as it won't save the index to the new file.

Comment: Loading the values to the csv file without the index got rid of the unwanted column, when I read the data back.

Comment: Glad to hear @StowCrates! Feel free to accept the answer in case it does replied and solved your question

Answer (score 0):

Just add index=False to the 'instancemethod' to_csv() and your csv reading and writing will be nice and neat.